# How to use the value of Blogger tags in custom Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

I've been trying to find out the name of the author of a post using javascript and blogger tags.

The name of the author is stored in the data tag `<data:post.author>`.

I want to detect that name in custom javascript code I wrote.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var author = &quot;<data:post.author>&quot;;
    document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = author;
</script>
```

But it doesn't extract the value from it. How can I get the value of that data tag to use inside javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to replace `<data:post.author>` with **`<data:post.author/>`** otherwise you will see the following error when saving theme code -

> The element type `"data:post.author"` must be terminated by the matching
>   end-tag `"</data:post.author>"`

Also, a thing to note is that, the `data:post` dictionary data layout tags will only work if they are added between the statement -

```
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
<!-- Your Code -->
</b:loop>
```

This `b:loop` is present inside the `Blog` widget.

If these data layout tags are used outside that `b:loop` statement, then they won't work because Blogger won't be able to find the dictionary of `data:post` (The globally available dictionaries in Blogger themes are `data:blog` , `data:view` , `data:skin` , `data:widgets` and `data:messages`)

Comment: I was actually trying to add the code using a javascript/html widget. I will try your suggestion. Thank you.